# Can I create a URL to send in email which will open a specific cart by id?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, url, session, persistent

I'm implementing an abandoned cart email solution. Is it possible in Magento to access a given cart simply by clicking a URL with the cart id somewhere? E.g. something like:

`https://www.mystore.com/cart?id=123456789`

The specific use case when this is needed is when someone clicks the link from a different device than where he was doing the shopping.

I'm particularly interested to find out if this is possible for **carts created by unlogged visitors** - for logged in people the [persistent cart option](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/sales/shopping-cart-persistent-setup.html) can be enabled, and then I only need to send the link to login.